# is there an r function for filtering ##NA## in a dataframe saved as a character

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, gps, na

I have the following data set whose character is ##NA##, that I want to filter

```
gps<-c("##NA##"," 36.8955044653751,-1.3190453373576","40.2380971776017,-0.423957630067816")
cluster<-c(147009,147009,147009)
data1<-data.frame(cluster,gps)
data1
```

The expected output is

```
gps<-c(" 36.8955044653751,-1.3190453373576","40.2380971776017,-0.423957630067816")
    cluster<-c(147009,147009)
    data2<-data.frame(cluster,gps)
    data2
```

Comment: `subset(data1, gps != '##NA##')`

Answer (score 0):

```r
gps<-c("##NA##"," 36.8955044653751,-1.3190453373576","40.2380971776017,-0.423957630067816")
cluster<-c(147009,147009,147009)
data1<-data.frame(cluster,gps)
data1
#>   cluster                                 gps
#> 1  147009                              ##NA##
#> 2  147009   36.8955044653751,-1.3190453373576
#> 3  147009 40.2380971776017,-0.423957630067816

data1[data1$gps != '##NA##',]
#>   cluster                                 gps
#> 2  147009   36.8955044653751,-1.3190453373576
#> 3  147009 40.2380971776017,-0.423957630067816
```